# Saving the HTML Canvas Context Stack online?

Tags: html, canvas, save, stack

Is there a simple way to save an HTML canvas stack for future manipulation?

I do not want to save the canvas as an image because I need to be able to edit the canvas at any time.

Ideally I would like to save the stack as a text file.

Answer (score 1):

Canvas does not have any built in way to do this. You would have to write a custom layer in between your code and the canvas layer to track the state.

Off the top of my head, the [Fabric](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js) canvas library has the ability to export the scene to JSON. See [Element.toDatalessJSON()](http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/docs/symbols/fabric.Element.html#toDatalessJSON) and [Element.loadDatalessJSON()](http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/docs/symbols/fabric.Element.html#loadFromDatalessJSON), which you can use on the root Fabric canvas element.